# What is the best way to clean up and remove stones from yard so I can grow grass

Tags: grass

I just purchased a new house in Pennsylvania and it seems like the old owners did not take care of the lawn very much at all. There are tons of bald spots that I want to grow grass in and weeds everywhere that I need to kill , but I think the first thing I want to do is find a way to take up and remove all of these stones that are is various parts of the lawn so I can grow grass there. Also, I’m assuming that I need to remove these stones before I try to grow grass, maybe I can just plant seed on top? Sorry, first time homeowner and I don’t know anything about landscaping. Please note that this is just one picture, I have patches of this all over my lawn.  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of hard to get the actual scale or size of those stones but they look awfully small. I wouldn't worry about any stones under maybe 1/2 inch in diameter. Just rake up what you can, depending on how packed the soil is, you can probably just rough it up some. Then seed and gently rake it in barely covering the seed. I put some straw over the top then to conserve moisture and keep it moist until you see the seed sprouting. The grass is going to look more like hair, very fine, at first, it takes time to establish itself.